# Unable to read in separate rows from .txt file (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code as follows:

```
def read_lines(csv_reader, row_list):
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if row_number in row_list:
            yield row_number, row

with open(file_name, 'r') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, dialect='tab_delim')
    r = list(range(4))
    r2 = list(range(4, 7))
    combined_list = []
    combined_list2 = []

for row_number, row in read_lines(reader, r):
    row_tuples = list(it.combinations(row, 2))
    combined_list.append(row_tuples)
```

This works fine for reading in the first 3 rows and generating the combined_list that I want. However, when I try to read in the second set of rows (4,7) later in my code using:

```
for row_number, row in read_lines(reader, r2):
    row_tuples = list(it.combinations(row, 2))
    combined_list.append(row_tuples)
```

The rows are not read in and the combined_list2 is empty.  I've attempted to troubleshoot but can't seem to figure out how to get this to work without closing the file and re-opening it (which I am trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using the same `reader` object, which has already been iterated, so the second time you call `read_lines` with it, it'll be empty.

You'll need to reset or recreate it - [Reset the csv.reader() iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984797/reset-the-csv-reader-iterator)

```
for row_number, row in read_lines(reader, r):
    # do stuff

# TODO: reset 'reader'

for row_number, row in read_lines(reader, r2):
    # do stuff
```

Alternatively, read all the lines into a single generator, then filter them out as you iterate once

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, dialect='tab_delim')
    r = list(range(4))
    r2 = list(range(4, 7))
    combined_list = []
    combined_list2 = []
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        data = list(it.combinations(row, 2))
        if row_number in r:
            combined_list.append(data)
        if row_number in r2:
            combined_list2.append(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I attempt to reset the csv.reader() iterator using reader.seek(0), I receive an error message saying that "_csv.reader object has no attribute seek". Will seek method not work using the csv module?

Comment: I think the comments in the code in that answer there are saying that it doesn't actually work...

Comment: Ah I see, I needed to use File.seek(0) instead of reader.seek(0) Your method worked upon fixing. Thanks!